# HTTP POST request на android

Tags: android, post

В моей цели было отправить POST запрос на мою PHP страницу. Просмотрел кучу сайтов и материалов сделал банальный HTTP request после чего у меня android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException вывело данную ошибку. Попробовал сделать через Asynctask только вот нормально ничего не понял и вот что вышло

```
package ktl.myapplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnOk;
    /**Вызывается при первом создании */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // загрузка layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                        try {
                            //создаем запрос на сервер
                            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

                            //он у нас будет посылать post запрос
                            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://shkz3.info/switch.php");
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PAR", "SVET1"));
                            //собераем их вместе и посылаем на сервер
                            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
    }

}
```

а также logcat

```
04-02 11:23:44.575  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize : 0
04-02 11:23:44.578  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get new systemTid : 32216
04-02 11:23:44.578  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-02 11:23:44.578  32216-32220/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: interp stack at 0x5ba49000
04-02 11:23:44.578  32216-32220/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
04-02 11:23:44.578  32216-32220/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32221/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: interp stack at 0x5bb69000
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32221/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32221/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32221/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ Elevating priority from 0 to -8
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jdwp﹕ prepping for JDWP over ADB
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32222/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: interp stack at 0x5ecaa000
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32222/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32222/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
04-02 11:23:44.579  32216-32222/ktl.myapplication D/jdwp﹕ JDWP: thread running
04-02 11:23:44.580  32216-32222/ktl.myapplication D/jdwp﹕ trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
04-02 11:23:44.625  32216-32228/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=9: interp stack at 0x5f43e000
04-02 11:23:44.625  32216-32228/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
04-02 11:23:44.625  32216-32228/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
04-02 11:23:44.625  32216-32229/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: interp stack at 0x5f55c000
04-02 11:23:44.625  32216-32229/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
04-02 11:23:44.625  32216-32229/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
04-02 11:23:44.655  32216-32222/ktl.myapplication D/jdwp﹕ received file descriptor 47 from ADB
04-02 11:23:44.669  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/SettingsProviderInterface﹕ invalidate [system]: current 244 != cached 0
04-02 11:23:44.670  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@43160db0,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@43161528
04-02 11:23:44.673  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/asset﹕ AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
04-02 11:23:44.676  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/Proxy﹕ setHttpRequestCheckHandler
04-02 11:23:44.678  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/ktl.myapplication-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ktl.myapplication-2.apk@classes.dex
04-02 11:23:44.680  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{4315e3e8 ktl.myapplication}}
04-02 11:23:44.680  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/ActivityThread﹕ Handling launch of ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}}
04-02 11:23:44.747  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@43165428, appName=ktl.myapplication, pkg=ktl.myapplication, comp={ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/ktl.myapplication-2.apk
04-02 11:23:44.749  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
04-02 11:23:44.749  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
04-02 11:23:44.749  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
04-02 11:23:44.749  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32230/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: interp stack at 0x5f726000
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32230/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32230/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32230/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: created from interp
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32230/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: notify debugger
04-02 11:23:44.750  32216-32230/ktl.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11 (LaunchIconThemeResource): calling run()
04-02 11:23:44.757  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/asset﹕ AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
04-02 11:23:44.800  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ LaunchIconThemeResourcegetDrawable packageName:ktl.myapplication asetfile:null
04-02 11:23:44.801  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ LaunchIconThemeResourcegetDrawable packageName:ktl.myapplication asetfile:null
04-02 11:23:44.803  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ LaunchIconThemeResourcegetDrawable packageName:ktl.myapplication asetfile:null
04-02 11:23:44.806  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ LaunchIconThemeResourcegetDrawable packageName:ktl.myapplication asetfile:null
04-02 11:23:44.807  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ LaunchIconThemeResourcegetDrawable packageName:ktl.myapplication asetfile:null
04-02 11:23:44.809  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}} finished=false
04-02 11:23:44.809  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}}
04-02 11:23:44.809  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
04-02 11:23:44.854  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/PhoneWindow﹕ DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4316c030 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-02 11:23:44.968  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/ActivityThread﹕ Resuming ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
04-02 11:23:44.968  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/PhoneWindow﹕ DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{43179d90 ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4316c030 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-02 11:23:44.968  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}}
04-02 11:23:44.969  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}}
04-02 11:23:44.971  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ FontThemeManager createThemeFont typefacetype=2, curfontpath=/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
04-02 11:23:44.971  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ FontThemeManager createThemeFont typefacetype=2, curfontpath=/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
04-02 11:23:44.971  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/jiayh2﹕ FontThemeManager createThemeFont typefacetype=2, curfontpath=/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
04-02 11:23:45.040  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/IMGSRV﹕ mtk_gralloc_debug_check:43: g_gr_dbg=0 v=-1
04-02 11:23:45.040  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/IMGSRV﹕ mtk_gralloc_debug_check:43: g_gr_dbg=0 v=-1
04-02 11:23:45.059  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x604a6910) (w:1088, h:1920, f:1)
04-02 11:23:45.063  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-02 11:23:45.064  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x60cd26b0) (w:1792, h:1984, f:1)
04-02 11:23:45.071  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ setViewport 1080x1920 <0x604a6a38>
04-02 11:23:45.073  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/InputMethodManager﹕ onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100
04-02 11:23:45.073  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/InputMethodManager﹕ START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4316c030 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1080,1920} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4318baf8 controlFlags=#104
04-02 11:23:46.466  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication I/View﹕ Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{43171f10 VFED..C. ........ 191,48-425,192 #7f08003f app:id/btn1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=117.71414, y[0]=76.89589, Xw[0]=16.0, Yw[0]=16.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=56834756, downTime=56834756, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
04-02 11:23:46.487  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x61bf4b60) (w:1088, h:1920, f:1)
04-02 11:23:46.570  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication I/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{43171f10 VFED..C. ...P.... 191,48-425,192 #7f08003f app:id/btn1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=112.71878, y[0]=74.89693, Xw[0]=32.0, Yw[0]=32.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=56834860, downTime=56834756, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
04-02 11:23:46.589  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x5f93dc58) (w:1088, h:1920, f:1)
04-02 11:23:48.835  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication I/View﹕ Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{43171f10 VFED..C. ........ 191,48-425,192 #7f08003f app:id/btn1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=131.7012, y[0]=108.87923, Xw[0]=16.0, Yw[0]=16.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=56837124, downTime=56837124, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
04-02 11:23:48.869  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x61a99778) (w:1088, h:1920, f:1)
04-02 11:23:49.127  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication I/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{43171f10 VFED..C. ...P.... 191,48-425,192 #7f08003f app:id/btn1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=131.7012, y[0]=108.87923, Xw[0]=32.0, Yw[0]=32.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=56837417, downTime=56837124, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
04-02 11:23:49.128  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication V/SettingsProviderInterface﹕ from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
04-02 11:24:26.220  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{4315fbe8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0 {ktl.myapplication/ktl.myapplication.MainActivity}}
04-02 11:24:26.238  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0
04-02 11:24:26.335  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-02 11:24:26.349  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x604a6910) (w:1088 h:1920 f:1)
04-02 11:24:26.350  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x61bf4b60) (w:1088 h:1920 f:1)
04-02 11:24:26.351  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x5f93dc58) (w:1088 h:1920 f:1)
04-02 11:24:26.352  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x61a99778) (w:1088 h:1920 f:1)
04-02 11:24:26.714  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 1)
04-02 11:24:26.715  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-02 11:24:26.720  32216-32216/ktl.myapplication D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@4315f2d0
```

Comment: Ваш логкат не содержит никаких ошибок, следовательно в нем смысла нет. Вы не вызываете hc.execute() и соответственно никакого результата вы не получаете. С чем конкретно у вас возникли проблемы?

Comment: На кнопку при нажатий ничего не происходит. а также значение не изменяется на сайте. я так понял его надо вызвать так  HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
                            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());

Answer (score 4):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` - означает что вы пытаетесь сконнектиться с сервером с основного (UI) потока.

Принято "садить" коннект и вообще работу с сетью на вспомогательный поток (`Thread`) или посредством рукопашного создания `Runnable/Thread` или что более кошерно через `AsyncTask`

Comment: ну я пробовал это сделать через AsyncTask этот код вы можете увидеть на странице

Comment: Ваш AsyncTask не запускается - отсутствует `execute()`

Answer (score 2):

> Google + Под что программируем? (Android) + Что хотим сделать?(http
>   post) + Что нибудь особенное?(AsyncTask) = [Google -> Android httppost
>   asynctask](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20httppost%20asynctask&es_th=1)

Дальше самым наглым образом открываем **первую ссылку**, и получаем ответ! (При этом экономим свое время, мое время, свои и мои нервы, избегаем иронии и сарказма по поводу своей ленивости, и т. д. Одни плюсы!)

Comment: я пытался искать, но вот только не особо понял как все это работает

Comment: @GalizhanTolybaev, мало описать класс, который наследуется от AsyncTask, нужно еще создать его экземпляр, и вызвать метод.    
Но раз вы этого не знаете, то ваших познаний по Java слишком мало для того, чтобы заниматься Android разработкой. Пройдите начальные курсы по Java и Android, а потом уже начинайте программировать. Сразу же исчезнут такие вопросы, которых у вас без этих курсов будет возникать тысячи. В сумме время, потраченое на решение этих вопросов будет значительно больше времени, потраченного на освоение курсов.

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления параметров:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("param1_key", "param1_value");
params.put("param2_key", "param2_value");
```

Для работы с Cookie:

```
PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext());
```

В итоге получим:

```
private void onServerPostQuery(){
    AsyncHttpClient mClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    PersistentCookieStore mCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext());
    mClient.setCookieStore(mCookieStore);
    mClient.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 10); // Установка таймаута соединения
    mClient.setResponseTimeout(1000 * 10); // Установка таймаута ожидания ответа
    String url = "Ваш URL";

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("param1_key", param1_val);
    params.put("param2_key", param2_val);
    params.put("param3_key", param3_val);

    mClient.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        private String response;
        private int status;

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            response = new String(responseBody);
            status = statusCode;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            response = error.toString();
            status = statusCode;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
            switch(status){
                case 200: // Сообщение от сервера получено
                    // Обрабатываем полученное сообщение
                    // Если есть ошибка в скриптах сервера, то она будет получена здесь
                    break;

                default:
                    // Ошибка internet

                    break;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле при использовании http://loopj.com/android-async-http все просто:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
String url = "http://www.google.com" // Ваш URL 

// Выполнение запроса
client.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

   String response;

@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
    // Выполняется при удачном запросе
    response = new String(response);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
    // Выполнится при неудачном запросе
    response = error.toString();
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    // Выполнится в любом случае при завершении процесса
    // Здесь можно обрабатывать ответ
}
```

});

Comment: если вам не сложно можете сказать куда писать параметры и почему   он не может распознать error

Answer (score 0):

пробуй, может поможет. Работает как на HTTPS и HTTP

```
//=============================================================================

String query = "https://site.com/api/v1/send_data";
String json = "{\"volume_system\":"+volume_system+
        ",\"volume_music\":"+volume_music+
        ",\"device_id\":"+device_id+
        ",\"bluetooth_isEnabled\":"+'"'+bluetooth_isEnabled+'"'+"}";
URL url = new URL(query);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();
// read the response
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

String inputStreamString = new Scanner(in,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
System.out.println(inputStreamString);
in.close();
conn.disconnect();
```